# R ggplot2 fit smoothed line to all data while having groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code makes each group have a different colored point on a scatterplot.

```
df = mtcars

df$cyl = factor(df$cyl)

ggplot(df, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, colour = cyl, group = cyl)) + 
  geom_point(size = 5) + 
  geom_smooth()
```

However, when I add a smooth line - a smoothed line is created for each group.  How do I add a smoothed line for all the data, while retaining the different group colors?

[image: Data coloured by group]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change location of colour and group will do

```
    df %>%
    ggplot( aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + 
      geom_point(size = 5, aes(colour = cyl, group = cyl)) + 
      geom_smooth()
```

[image]